# Question regarding affine fibre bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, sheaf-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of affine varieties such that it is a fibre bundle with fibre $F$. Let $\pi_1(Y)=\Gamma$ be a free group (non abelian) of finite rank and $\pi_1(F)$ is a finite group $G$ say and $\pi_2(Y)=0$. Let $g:Z\to X$ be a topological covering projection corresponding to $\Gamma$ and assume that fibres $(f\circ g)^{-1}(c)$ are universal covers of $f^{-1}(c)$ for all $c\in Y$.
Using Serre's long exact sequence of homotopy we see that $\Gamma$ and $G$ are both subgroups of $\pi_1(X)$.
My question is: is $\Gamma$ a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$ i.e. is $g:Z\to X$ a regular covering?

Any comments or reference how to tackle the question will be very helpful.

Comment: There is something not quite right here. It follows from the assumptions on $X$ and $Y$ that $F$ is a $K(G,1)$, so it cannot be finite dimensional (unless $G=\{e\}$).

Comment: Thanks @algori. I have edited the question now.

Comment: Typically $\Gamma$ would act nontrivially on $G$, so $\pi_1(X)$ would be a semidirect product, and the subgroup would not be normal.

Comment: Can you give an example?